# Advantages and disadvantages of using prime faces over rich faces

Tags: seam, seam2, jboss-seam

For Seam 2.3, what are advantages and disadvantages of using Prime Faces over Rich Faces?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combind them both if you want to.

However, PrimeFace have a much more active community and more steady development, and better documentation.

Would recomend PrimceFace over Richface , but i think both works well.

Answer (score 0):

We've used both (rich: for ui components and ajax, prime: for page layout) in our project because it was quite fast to build nice pages with "minimum" effort. Later on we faced performance issues of rich:datatable, rish:suggestionbox, ajax, huge JS code generated by both prime and rich, different css, etc. Also, prime sometimes asks for payment to provide good support. Now, I would prefer not using them at all, just JSF, Seam tags, Seam remoting and jquery for nice UI and ajax.